# Build a maven product with components from a different git repository

Tags: maven

Our project has two different git repositories A and B. Both A and B are multi module projects. B's code is finally built as a eclipse product using maven parent pom. B requires a component/ feature from A which needs to be included in the eclipse product. How can I achieve this functionality. Do I need to publish the results of A's build to a webserver, so that B can access it as a repository? or can I include A as dependency to B's build so that B can package this component in the final product? Where/ how can I specify this configuration?

Let me know if any other information is required.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using Jenkins CI server to achieve this functionality. Do I need to set up both builds separately or can I do this using the same build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible on your local machine if you run 'mvn install' on project A. If you want the artifact from project A to be available to other developers you need to setup a maven repository such as Archiva and run 'mvn deploy' instead

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using Jenkins CI server to achieve this functionality, which means I need to checkout code from A first and run the build and then run build B, correct?

Comment: thats correct. The same applies to Jenkins, you have run the install goal as part of the build. Alternately, you could try the 'copy artifact' plugin

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. I ran mvn install option locally for build A and then ran build B separately with mvn install. I mentioned the dependency of feature x present in A as a dependency in B's .product file. However, during B's build, it is not able to recognize this dependency. Am I missing some finer details?

Comment: <projectname.product> file is used to build eclipse product/RCP and has all the configurations for the product defined eg. dependencies/features, VM args, launcher name,branding,licencing info etc..

Answer (score 1):

You should at least deploy project A to the local repository (mvn install). Then it will be available to project B through maven.